# Highcharts displays wrong month (next month) in datetime chart

Tags: datetime, highcharts, timezone, timezone-offset

As mentioned in the title, Highcharts displays the next month instead of the correct month that I want to be shown.

```
<script>

$(function () {
    Highcharts.setOptions({
        global: {
            //timezoneOffset: 3.30 * 60
        }
    });

    $('#container').highcharts({
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            tickInterval: 3600 * 1000,
            min: Date.UTC(2016,02,20),
            max: Date.UTC(2016,02,21),
        },
        series: [{
            data: [
                [Date.UTC(2016, 02, 20,0,45), 1],
                [Date.UTC(2016, 02, 20,12,15), 3],
                [Date.UTC(2016, 02, 20,14,30), 6],
                [Date.UTC(2016, 02, 20,15,45), 9],
                [Date.UTC(2016, 02, 20,17,45), 5],
                ],
            pointStart: Date.UTC(2016, 02, 20),
            pointInterval: 3600 *1000
        }]
    });
});
</script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

So as per the code I provide I want it to display Feb in xAxis but it jumps to March instead.

How can I fix this to display  the month that I want?

Does Highcharts use the user timezone? How can I display a fixed timezone and avoid using user timezone?

https://jsfiddle.net/v4kasmv1/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just edit 02 to 01 for Feb `min: Date.UTC(2016,01,20)` as 00 for Jan, 01 for Feb and 02 for March:

```
$(function () {
    Highcharts.setOptions({
        global: {
            //timezoneOffset: 3.30 * 60
        }
    });

    $('#container').highcharts({
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            tickInterval: 3600 * 1000,
            min: Date.UTC(2016,01,20),
            max: Date.UTC(2016,01,21),
        },
        series: [{
            data: [
                [Date.UTC(2016, 01, 20,0,45), 1],
                [Date.UTC(2016, 01, 20,12,15), 3],
                [Date.UTC(2016, 01, 20,14,30), 6],
                [Date.UTC(2016, 01, 20,15,45), 9],
                [Date.UTC(2016, 01, 20,17,45), 5],
                ],
            pointStart: Date.UTC(2016, 01, 20),
            pointInterval: 3600 *1000
        }]
    });
});
```

Comment: SkyFloor, Javascript Date.UTC function expects month to be 0 through 11, so "editing" xAxis data is not some hack to get the right month to show, but is instead referring to your need to use the correct value in order to get the right month to show, in this instance.  http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getutcmonth.asp